# Football - Who gets the match ball, if 2 or more players score hat-tricks in a game?

Tags: rules, football

In football, if a player scores a hat-trick, he usually takes the match ball with him as a souvenir.

But if 2 or more players score a hat-trick in a single game, then who gets to take the match ball with him?

Comment: There is not the one match ball, so if they really both want one, the second one will have to pick one from a ball boy.

Comment: @ThomasDB - While what you say can be true, but could you help by providing some references. Thx.

Comment: A reference to multiple balls being used in a game?

Comment: I doubt there is anything mandating what would happen. This is more of a custom than a rule ... the normal one hat trick going to the scorer is just a gift he gets ...

Comment: References which show that these circumstances have happened.

Comment: I honestly do not think it ever happened at all, it's also not that common to take the match ball after a hattrick. I watch easily 10 games a week and have no recollection of a player taking/getting the ball after he has scored a hattrick. I was just trying to point out the sillyness of the possibility of two players fighting over a match ball if there are used more than one in a game. That's also why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ThomasDB: the fact that you don't see (or recall) it doesn't mean it doesn't happen: here is a picture of Messi posing with all the balls he scored hat-tricks with (http://bit.ly/1E0Q6OZ), and here is one of Ronaldo doing the same (http://bit.ly/1KyvC52). A google search for "takes hat-trick goal" returns several images of hat-trick scorers leaving the field with the ball in their hands, or getting it signed by their teammates.

Comment: @Koldito, I was not saying that taking the ball does not happen. I was pointing out the uncommonness of it, which leads to the question being obsolete.

Comment: @ThomasDB - something being a little uncommon does not mean it is obsolete. I think it makes it more interesting on the other hand.

Comment: The players who scored a hat trick do not need to have the ball.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As usual, the very excellent *The Knowledge* series of *The Guardian* has an answer. The [January 28, 2004](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2004/jan/28/theknowledge.sport) entry goes like this:

> "**On Sunday, Empoli drew 3-3 with Juventus, Tommaso Rocchi bagging a hat-trick for the home side, and David Trezeguet claiming all three goals for Juve," says Stuart Bruce. "With the scorers of hat-tricks traditionally claiming the match ball, who gets to take it home in a situation like this? Has there ever been a situation of three or more players all with a valid claim to the match ball in any one match?**"
>
> But, we have consulted with the FA stattos on this one and are told that though there are no rules, the convention would in all likelihood be that the first player to score a hat-trick would receive the match ball. Thus, as Rocchi completed his hat-trick in the 62nd minute, 14 minutes before Trezeguet made it 3-3, the Empoli striker should have be the one making space on his mantelpiece, which we hope is level or else the ball will keep rolling off it.
>
> As far as your second question goes Stuart, there are in fact several examples of three players scoring a hat-trick in one game. The last instance - which, incidentally, is also the last instance of a team scoring 10 goals in an English league game - comes from November 7 1987, when Manchester City beat Huddersfield Town 10-1 in the old Second Division.

Answer (score 7):

On Wednesday February 3rd, 2016, FC Barcelona vs Valencia, in the Copa Del Rey, Luis Suarez and Messi both scored a hat-trick. Suarez scored 4 goals, Messi scored 3 goals. At the end of the match, they both left with a football.

Sources:

- [Luis Suárez hits four, Lionel Messi three as Barcelona rout Valencia 7-0](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2016/feb/03/lionel-messi-luis-suarez-hat-tricks-barcelona-valencia)
- [Lionel Messi’s ‘great gesture’ with Luis Suarez over match ball](http://lebuzz.eurosport.co.uk/viral/lionel-messis-great-gesture-with-luis-suarez-over-match-ball-10751/)

[image: Messi and Suarez with match balls]

Comment: I have added some links, so that the claims in this answer are not without any reference. I hope you do not mind.